# Does flanking grant combat advantage to all allies?

Tags: dnd-4e

Does a properly flanked enemy only grant combat advantage to the allies doing the flanking, or to all allies?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**No**

Only the allies in flanking positions get combat advantage.

However, there is a feat that allows a ranged attack to benefit from flanking allies. It's called `Distant Advantage`

There is also a feat for half-elf rogues that does exactly this called `Group Flanking`

Finally, there is `Vexing Flanker`, which does exactly what you are talking about without the class/race specificity.